# Regex to find 5 words before and after a word

Tags: c#, regex

I need to write a Regex to find 5 words before and after a word.
Here is what I have -

```
(?:\S+ +){0,5}\bHELLO\b(?: \S+){0,5}
```

It matches fine for  :

```
WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD HELLO WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD
```

But not in : `WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD HELLO-1 WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD WORD`

How can I include - or any specific special char in regex.

Comment: Do you mean you can have a hyphenated number as suffix? Try `(?:\S+ +){0,5}\bHELLO(?:-\d+)?\b(?: +\S+){0,5}`. Or, there can be any amount of hyphenated words? Try the `(?:\S+ +){0,5}\bHELLO(?:-\w+)*\b(?: +\S+){0,5}` pattern then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the 2nd one, how can we include multiple types of special chars, e.g. hyphen or colon or percentile etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:\S+ +){0,5}\bHELLO(?:[:%-]\w+)*\b(?: +\S+){0,5}
```

Note:

- The `-` char is at the end of the character class, where it does not have to escaped. If you put it at the start of the character class, you won't have to escape it either. Else, escape it.
- Escape `^` if you put it at the start of the character class
- Escape `]` if you do not put it at the start of the character class.
- Always escape `\` char.

The `(?:[:%-]\w+)*` pattern is a non-capturing group that matches zero or more repetitions (due to `*`) of a `:`, `%` or `-` char followed with one or more word chars.

Comment: This works, but the second part to fetch 5 words after is not working anymore. (?: +\S+){0,5}

Comment: @ADeveloper [It works fine](https://regex101.com/r/lvDGbM/1).